# How to represent two positions in parallel in Developer Story?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I was an exchange student for a few months. Is there a way to show that in Developer Story?

Right now, my exchange semester (from september 2016 to december 2016) is displayed BEFORE my school (from september 2014 to current). It doesn't look right to me.

Is there a way to put two positions in parallel, or to show that a position was part of another?